# AKS logs don't show timestamp

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have to connected to AKS cluster from cmd(windows), when i list the logs of a pod, timestamp of the logs are not in human readable format
Timestamp are displayed like below, please can some one help to get this fixed
Export of timestamp to a txt also doesn't work

**[0m[0m14:41:04,468**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaE0N.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to view your logs in **human readable format** from windows, using powershell / cmd run the command
`kubectl logs your-pod-name -n your-namespace --your-required-parameter`

Example:

`kubectl logs your-pod-name -n your-namespace --timestamps`

So, in my case I have an AKS cluster where few pods are running as below.
[image]

Now suppose I want to view the logs for my first pod in **human readable format**, suppose I want the timestamp in human readable format then I will use.

```
kubectl logs kyverno-admission-controller-757766c5f5-g8l2j -n kyverno --timestamps
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Arko, i can see the timestamp now
But this displays logs like below

2023-10-18T05:09:22.765391034Z [0m[0m05:09:22,761 INFO
How can we get the timestamp removed , which is not useful from the logs anymore? 
*([0m[0m05:09:22,761)*
And please can you help to understand what is the value 765391034Z, displayed in the readable timestamp